# Refer To A Jenkins Parent Workspace From Child

Tags: jenkins

I have a child configuration in Jenkins that can be triggered from 3 separate parent configs.

The purpose of this is to run Sonar on my code. I could add a post build step to each of the parents, but if anything changes I have to change it in 3 places and something is likely to get missed.

Therefore, I can see a few options:

- the child has to run on the same slave as the parent and needs access to the parent workspace via a variable.
- the svn url is transferred to the child and the code is checked out
- the parent workspace is zipped up and transferred to the child (slave independent)

The first option seems to be the lowest on netweork impact (especially as the workspace is very big).

Which of these is possible in Jenkins and how do I do it?

Comment: We had the exact same problem and went with the first option. I'll be interested to see if there's a better solution.

Comment: So how did you force the child to be on the same slave and refer to the parent workspace?

Comment: You can set the slave on the jobs then you know then names of the workspaces so you can refer to them using relative paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the [Shared workspace plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Shared+workspace+plugin) in my Jenkins environment.

My Linux master build a Maven project and I need to share the workspace (with the compiled sources) with a Windows slave to build a MSI package.

You just have to add a post build action on the parent job to compress the workspace (workspace size: around 1GB).

The VMs are in the same physical network and it takes less than 2 minutes to compress the workspace:

```
01:33:28 Archiving workspace
01:35:15 Deleting old workspace snapshot from #160
```

Next, the child job can use the parent workspace as a SCM source:

[image]

Does it help?

Comment: I couldn't get the admins to install the plugin and I have left the project but I will accept as it seems to be a reasonable answer.